# call method without object in java?

Tags: java

My teacher gave me an assignment which said to have this list:

```
int[] list = {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103};
```

and to have this method for binarySearch:

```
public class binarySearch {

    public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int target, int min, int max) {

        if (min > max) {
            return -1;        // target not found
        } else {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (a[mid] < target) {         // too small; go right
                return binarySearch(a, target, mid + 1, max);
            } else if (a[mid] > target) {  // too large; go left
                return binarySearch(a, target, min, mid - 1);
            } else {
                return mid;   // target found; a[mid] == target
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then she says to test it by calling it with these statements:

```
public class arrayDriver{
    public static void main(String []args){


       int[] list = {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103};


        System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9));
        System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 30, 2, 8));
    }
}
```

It all makes sense but when I do that, I get the error

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

and my first guess is because I haven't made an object and haven't done, for example, `list.binarySearch();`. So I'm confused on how this works? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to create an instance to call a `static` method; did you put those `println` statements in a `main` method?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @tohrchur  can you post complete code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes it was in the main method.

Comment: @FastSnail that was essentially the complete code. here is the link to the assignment. http://pages.towson.edu/kpark/courses/Java2/Labs/Lab7.htm

Comment: @Tohrchur no i mean the your complete code.with class declaration not just methods

Comment: @FastSnail main method: http://pastebin.com/4gTpX98A  method: http://pastebin.com/tgWZC7nZ  Im not really sure what to do thats why im asking.

Comment: And your complete exception, I just ran it; it works fine.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's just giving me an error. Not sure why..?

Comment: Post your code here; not on pastebin links (paste, highlight and press ctrl-k to add necessary spaces).

Comment: opps so there is 2 classes .you can call `binarySearch.binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9)`

Comment: And put the `binarySearch` method in your `main` class. Not a second class; or access it by class name. Java naming convention has classes start with a capital letter.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks I got it, the way she explained it made it seem like I needed a separate file to call on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different classes. Have the main method in the same class as the binarysearch method:

```
public class BinarySearch{

public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int target, int min, int max) {

    if (min > max) {
        return -1;        // target not found
    } else {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (a[mid] < target) {         // too small; go right
            return binarySearch(a, target, mid + 1, max);
        } else if (a[mid] > target) {  // too large; go left
            return binarySearch(a, target, min, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return mid;   // target found; a[mid] == target
        }
    }

public static void main(String []args){


       int[] list = {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103};

        System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9));
        System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 30, 2, 8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, this code:

```
public static void main(String []args){


   int[] list = {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103};


    System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 30, 2, 8));
}
```

is in a class called `arrayDriver`. This code:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int target, int min, int max) {

    if (min > max) {
        return -1;        // target not found
    } else {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (a[mid] < target) {         // too small; go right
            return binarySearch(a, target, mid + 1, max);
        } else if (a[mid] > target) {  // too large; go left
            return binarySearch(a, target, min, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return mid;   // target found; a[mid] == target
        }
    }
}
```

is in a different class called `binarySearch`.

In Java, you can only access methods directly (i.e. no suffixes) if the caller is in the same class as the method. So if your `main` method is in `binarySearch` instead of `arrayDriver`, the code will work. So...

**Solution 1**

Put the main method in the `binarySearch` class

**Solution 2**

Put the `binarySearch` method in the `arrayDriver` class

Let's suppose that you cannot change the class of either of those methods. You can call `binarySearch` by adding a class name suffix, which is `binarySearch.`

**Solution 3**

```
System.out.println(binarySearch.binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep them as separate classes you can just extend the BinarySearch class from your ArrayDriver class.

```
public class ArrayDriver extends BinarySearch{

   public static void main(String []args){


       int[] list = {-2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103};


       System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 103, 0, 9));
       System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 30, 2, 8));
   }
}
```

This will allow you to use any public/protected variables/methods created in your BinarySearch class without having to explicitly create an instance of that class.